# Tag synonym request: [rebasing] -> [rebase]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

- [rebasing](/questions/tagged/rebasing) : 13 questions
- [rebase](/questions/tagged/rebase): 182 questions

Comment: What is 'rebasing'?

Comment: @PaddedCell The gerund of "to rebase" was my guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not synonyms, [rebasing](/questions/tagged/rebasing) mostly refers to .Net JIT or DLL rebasing, while [rebase](/questions/tagged/rebase) mostly refers to GIT.

While *some* questions (the minority) on [the rebasing list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rebasing) should be retagged, it shouldn't be done globally.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: And questions tagged [tag:rebasing] are now properly.